# How to reduce uncached page generation time?

Tags: mysql, optimization

On uncached pages, I have been able to bring down database query timinings to less than 0.2 seconds with sql tuning. However, the page generation time is still around 2 seconds as seen below via query monitor plugin:

[image: Page timings]

How to reduce this timing?

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple general answer for this, as it depends on what is causing the issue.

Best way is to check your page using some Insights tool:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/
https://gtmetrix.com/

They will tell you where the issue is.

Big images are commonly a big issue - there are many converters to WebP format, that will lower load speed.

You can try to load only JS and CSS files that are required on certain page.

If you have some big operations in PHP executed before page is loaded, you can try to reduce those.

But as I said, make the metrics check, and they will tell you what you need to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Page generation time refers to the time it took for the server to execute the SQL queries and generate the document's HTML. Tools like PageSpeed Insights and GTMetrix will not help identify this.

Because you already have Query Monitor plugin installed, I recommend reading [Query Monitor's documentation](https://querymonitor.com/docs/) to ensure proper usage, as well as add profiling to your code to identify where the time is being spent.